# Convert date-time string to Date in excel

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

I have  two columns with date-time values such as "2019-08-15T00:45:28.228Z". I want to convert each of them into date format columns, and then find number of minutes between the dates.

eg:

```
| A1                       | A2                       | Date(A1) | Date(A2) | A2-A1 in minutes |
|--------------------------|--------------------------|----------|----------|------------------|
| 2019-08-15T00:45:28.228Z | 2019-08-15T00:55:28.228Z |          |          | 10               |
| 2019-07-25T00:45:45.127Z | 2019-07-25T01:25:55.127Z |          |          | 40               |
```

I have not been able to convert the columns into a date format, because it has a time element as well, and all online examples seem to be only for date

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. You should make your own research. Just copy and paste your question title on Google and you will got many answers.like [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/convert-date-string-to-date-time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the data time all we need to do is remove the T and the Z so:

```
=--REPLACE(LEFT(A2,23),11,1," ")
```

Then format to the desired format.

[image]

Then a simple subtraction of the dates and a format of `[mm]` will return the desired output.

[image]

Comment: Is it the `--` that forces conversion to a number? Is this likely to be a hack that *may* not be present in later versions of Excel?

Comment: @Paul not a hack. It is -1*-1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LEFT` function to retrieve the date (it will then be displayed in its original format, like `2019-08-15`), or simply do `--LEFT` to convert the result to a number and change its formatting to `Date` using Excel:

[image]

Then use `MID` function to retrieve the times and do your `A2-A1` calculation (format the last column as `Time`):

[image]

**Update** - as per Paul's suggestion, the length of the syntax will always be the same so you could use the following functions:

```
=--LEFT(A2,10)
=MID(A2,12,12)
```

Comment: You could optimise this, as the dates and times are a standard IEEE format - the T will always be in the same location, as will the Z (i.e. at the end of the time, `LENGTH - 1`).

Comment: Ah fair point, the lengths will always be the same. Many thanks - I'll update the answer.

Comment: to get the date and time in one step all you need to do then is `=LEFT(A2,10)+MID(A2,12,12)`

Comment: Good one, thanks @ScottCraner. I just thought that OP wanted to display dates (without times) in columns C&D. Agreed that having it included makes the whole solution cleaner.

Comment: @ScottCraner - You may need to include a space in the middle - `=LEFT(A2,10) & " " & MID(A2,12,12)`.

Comment: @Paul no, because we are adding numbers not creating a text string.  By adding the date part and the time part we get a number that can be formatted into a date/time.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Wow!  I didn't realise that Excel would convert the values like that! I'm more of a database kind of guy, so everything is far more literal. Thanks for the info! :o)